# How to inject DismissAction instance for writing tests

Tags: swiftui, modal-dialog, dismiss

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ChildView(parentDismiss: dismiss)
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("close")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChildView.swift

```
struct ChildView: View {
    let parentDismiss: DismissAction

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            parentDismiss()
        } label: {
            Text("Close")
        }
    }
}
```

To write snapshot tests for ChildView, how do I go about creating a DismissAction instance?

```
class ChildViewSnapshotTests: XCTestCase {
    func testView() {
        let dismissAction = DismissAction()
        let view = ChildView(parentDimiss: dismissAction)
        assertSnapshot(view: view)
    }    
}
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like above. But DismissAction cant be initialised this way

Comment: Why can't you use `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` in `ChildView`?

Comment: it doesn't dismiss the parent view which the modal view

Answer (score 0):

From the context, it seems like you don't need a `DismissAction` that does a particular thing. You just want any instance of `DismissAction` so that you can create an instance of `ChildView`. In that case, you can get a "default" `DismissAction` by using

```
ChildView(parentDimiss: EnvironmentValues().dismiss)
```

Alternatively, allow `ChildView` to take an optional `DismissAction`. If it is nil, do nothing:

```
let parentDismiss: DismissAction?

var body: some View {
    Button {
        parentDismiss?()
    } label: {
        Text("Close")
    }
}
```

---

If you do need to pass a `DismissAction` that does a particular thing, you would need to pass a `() -> Void` to `ChildView` instead.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ChildView(parentDismiss: {
                    dismiss()
                })
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("close")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let parentDismiss: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            parentDismiss()
        } label: {
            Text("Close")
        }
    }
}
```